# Excel calculate SUM of differences when cell addresses are not fixed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel I have a list of employees (see image) and I want to store their salary update history. For each salary update, I want to calculate the difference in their total salary. I'm unable to create a formula to calculate this and `SUM()` the updates per period for me.

The image below demonstrates my spreadsheet and the desired salary update total (I did calculations manually, bet need a formula for this). In reality, there will be a few dozens of employees, so the requirement for the formula is to be dynamic and not contain manual "+" for each row.

[image: Example of my spreadsheet]

**NOTE:** For some people their salary can stay unchanged and there are not any values in some cells. It's the main challenge, since we have to find the value of the "previous salary" for an employee, because it's not necessary stored in the previous cell. Otherwise, I could have used a simple array formula, like:
**{=SUM(G3:G6-H3:H6)}**. But unfortunately, it does not work in this case (there can be no value in the H column, so we have to find where it actually is).

Also, the formula should work correctly with filtering: is some row is filtered out (person is inactive, see picture), this row/cell should be ignored.

Can anybody help me with this formula that I'm struggling with?

Comment: You forgot to add the picture.

Comment: What formula did you use to do the manual calculation?

Comment: I'm new on Stackoverflow and it doesn't let me embed images into the questions. I attached a link to the picture at the top of the question (see "Example of my spreadsheet" link).

Comment: I'm probably missing the point here but I don't understand how you are performing your manual calculations in the spreadsheet. If we take the example of the first column (**D**), you get $200 by: `1700-1500`. I can see the `1700` but why are you subtracting that by `1500`?

Comment: So, before 1700 (cell D5), an employee's salary was 1500 (see column F5). So, on 04/01/2018 we changed it from 1500 to 1700. Since it was the only change on that date, it means that the total raise on 04/01/2018 was only $200.

Comment: Are the salaries always increasing as you go from right to left? If so I can see a way of doing it, otherwise it looks very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you ask, not my my best work.Column `"I"`is still `=SUM`. Remember to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. Then drag the formula where you want it to apply.

`{=IFERROR(IF(E3="",E3,E3-INDEX(F3:$I$3,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(F3:$I$3),0)))
+IF(E4="",E4,E4-INDEX(F4:$I$4,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(F4:$I$4),0)))
+IF(E5="",E5,E5-INDEX(F5:$I$5,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(F5:$I$5),0)))
+IF(E6="",E6,E6-INDEX(F6:$I$6,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(F6:$I$6),0)));SUM(E3:E6))}`
[image: Example]

Comment: Thank you Justin for your reply. As I see, you manually added individual rises into the formula. It works fine with my example, but in real case there will be a few dozens of employees. Adding them all into the formula will make it difficult to maintain. 
Ideally, I would see this formula as SUM of salary updates for each row/employee. In this case, if we add a new row/employee to the spreadsheet, we should not modify all the formulas to add a new "+IF..." there. This is something I tried to achieve with no lack so far.

Answer (score 0):

This formula does give the same answers as yours on the test data as below, *BUT* it is making a very big assumption - that the last recorded salary is always the largest one.

```
=SUM(IF(D3:D6="",0,D3:D6-SUBTOTAL(4,OFFSET(E3,ROW(D3:D6)-ROW(D3),0,1,COLUMNS(E3:$J3)))))
```

[image]

Must be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you want to ignore hidden rows, plz use the form of Subtotal that ignores hidden cells

```
=SUM(IF(D3:D6="",0,SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(D3,ROW(D3:D6)-ROW(D3),0,1,1))-SUBTOTAL(104,OFFSET(E3,ROW(D3:D6)-ROW(D3),0,1,COLUMNS(E3:$J3)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This almost what is needed, but with one exception. I added one comment after your reply: the formula should work correctly with filtering: if some row is filtered out (person is inactive, see the first column on the question picture), this row should be ignored in the SUM calculation.

Comment: OK you should just be able to use the form of SUBTOTAL that ignores hidden rows - will add it to my answer.